# Wordpress and Angular 7. How to get asset path?

Tags: angular, wordpress, assets

I'm struggling to make Angular 7 and Wordpress work together. Well, actually, I've managed to make it to work without any plugins, that was not too hard itself, but I can't seem to make angular get any assets. The problem is that my Angular app sits on a URL like
https://mywordpresssite.com/dashboard 
And my angulare project uses assets folter to store its images. When I build the app and place it on my site, Angular tries to get its assets from https://mywordpresssite.com/dashboard/assets/... (its base url is poiting to /dashboard) and, of course, wordpress spits out 404 page. 
In wordpress itself I'm getting different images like this:

```
function _img($image_name) {
    echo get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/{$image_name}";
}
```

I wanted to use some custom routes and I've made a route to https://mywordpresssite.com/assets using this class https://github.com/anthonybudd/WP_route
like this

```
WP_Route::get("assets/{image_name}", 'get_image_for_angular');
function get_image_for_angular($image_name) {
    echo get_template_directory_uri() . "/{$image_name}";
}
```

And it shows the correct path to the file but nonetheless, wordpress still shows 404 along with that.

I also tried to use file_get_contents, it shows the image's bytes and 404 contents after that

I'm completely stuck with this. Can anyone help me resolve this? 
What is the corrent way to make Angular aware of the WP's asstets

p.s. My Angular project lives in other repo itself and does not know anything about the site's structure. I'm only building it to my site. I don't want to use any absolute paths, I need to keep angular as it is

Comment: The web server is rewriting all URL requests through Wordpress. If you're using Apache then update the `.htaccess` to allow access to that folder. Otherwise, move the assets to a folder in Wordpress used for assets. I know there is one, but I can't remember the name.

Comment: All WP assets are stored inside themes directories and I have access to them. But angular has no idea of what they are. That's why I'm looking for some elegant way to tell Angular the correct assets root url

Comment: It's not Angular that has no idea. It's just a URL... the reason it works is because the base HREF is set in the header of the HTML. I agree, it's a pain to access outside that scope, but this is Wordpress. It's not the nicely place to host a SPA framework even if it's React, Vue or Angular. A little hacking will be necessary. Just pick the hack that is the easiest to remember and change in the future.

Comment: Looks like my hack with redirection and routes works almost fine. It's problem (the problem of WP_Route, I believe) is that it gets confused when filename matches one of the routes. E.g. dashboard.css. If I try to open my dashboard having a file with the name of dashboard.css in one of my routes the dashboard request gets redirected to the file even though the path doesn't match exactly. Not much of a problem though, I can include css files another way. Yes, I understand that wordpress (or some other CMS) is not the best solution for this but it will do as a temporary one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this by now. Here is my solution

```
WP_Route::get("assets/img/{image_name}", 'get_image_for_angular');
function get_image_for_angular($image_name) {
    $path = get_template_directory_uri() . "/img/{$image_name}";
    header("Location: {$path}", TRUE, 301);
    exit();
}
```

It works. But I feel something bad about this. So I would still appreciate if someone told me about a better approach

Comment: Is this for a Wordpress plug-in? If so, you should move the assets during the plug-in installation.

Comment: it's not. I only need to add an angular app to my site

Comment: Do you meanwhile have a more constant solution for this? I'm struggling with the same problem.. frustrating! :-)